# Is there a simple method to keep Mercurial from accepting section of code for commit?

Tags: mercurial

I have a change to a file which I explicitly never want to commit to the repo.  (In this case, its a hack around a bug that needs to be resolved by fixing an unrelated codebase.)

Is there a way to mark the change so that Hg will error out if I try to commit it?  Ideally, it would be something inline in a comment so that I could choose to not commit that section of code (with TortoiseHg) and still be able to commit other portions.

Currently, I just have the change labelled with a nasty comment block, but it would be a great security blanket if I could tell the repo that this is dangerous code.

Comment: No, mercurial has no such functionality out of the box.

Comment: I expect that.  I was hoping for a client-side commit hook or similar.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to writing a hook is to commit the change, and move it to the `secret` phase. This will prevent ever pushing it to another repository. It also allows you to easily apply the change on top of any changeset by rebasing the secret commit.

Use a bookmark or a named branch to make the changeset easy to select.

```
hg branch externalbugworkaround
hg commit -m "HACK - workaround external bug. DO NOT PUSH"
hg phase -s -f externalbugworkaround
```

then to move it around

```
hg rebase --keepbranches -d rev -r externalbugworkaround
```

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest yourself: the solution is to write a client-side commit hook which parses the file with a regex and errors-out when the code you want to skip committing is part of the commit.

A simple hook which checks for bad file extensions and commit messages is found [for instance here](https://hg.openttdcoop.org/misc/files/tip/mercurial/hooks/check_commit.py) - it should be easy to extend to checking a certain file for a specific pattern.